# input value inside modal always get last record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem in my code, I have a table that contains of details of user and in every row it has 2 buttons: edit and delete. When the button is clicked, it calls a modal. As an example, if I click the edit-button, it will show a modal that displays my data in placeholder.

My question is: Why is the value of the input placeholder always filled with the last record from my table?

Here is the code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">No</th>
            <th scope="col">Nama</th>
            <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
            <th scope="col">Tempat/Tanggal Lahir</th>
            <th scope="col">No Telp</th>
            <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i=1;?>
        <?php foreach($daftar_user as $ds):?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?=$i;?></th>
            <td><?=$ds['nama'];?></td>
            <td><?=$ds['alamat'];?></td>
            <td><?=Date(' D m',$ds['tanggal_lahir']);?></td>
            <td><?=$ds['notelp'];?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="" data-target="#editprofile" data-toggle="modal" class="badge badge success">Edit
                    Profile</a>
                <a href="" class="badge badge-danger">Hapus Profile</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i++; endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ediprofileTitle"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ediprofileTitle">Edit Profile</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form action="<?=base_url('admin/manajemen_akun');?>" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="<?=$ds['id'];?>">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formnama" name="formnama"
                        placeholder="<?=$ds['nama'];?>">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formalamat" name="formalamat"
                        placeholder="<?=$ds['alamat'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are filling your Modal using PHP. That wont work, you have to use javascript so you can pick out the actual values of the row in the table that were clicked by the user

Comment: Is the *value* filled with the last record from the table, or is the *placeholder* filled with the last record from the table?  I don't see anything that's populating the value here, but you're explicitly populating the placeholder with that data.

Comment: i want the placeholder is fill with the curent value from the row but it always get filled with last record on my table

Comment: @BayuZangetsu: Because when you populate it server-side the `$ds` variable contains the last row, since it's after the loop.  You only have *one* modal in your markup, so if you populate its values server-side then you can only populate *one* set of values.  If you want to update the values in the browser then you'll need to use JavaScript.  Possibly responding to whatever event shows the modal and reading the values you want from that HTML row to update the modal's values.

Comment: Because you are filling it from the PHP I presume AFTER you completed this `foreach($daftar_user as $ds):?>` loop. So `$ds` will contain the last row from your resultset. You CANNOT DO THIS IN PHP you have to write some JAVASCRIPT because you want the modal to contain data from the table line that was clicked by the user IN THE BROWSER

Comment: so the solution is using Javascript, thanks for all of you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. You can place your required datas as attributes inside edit link as follows. Here I placed your datas in **data-id** , **data-name** and **data-alamat** attributes.

```
<a href="" data-target="#editprofile"  data-id="<?php echo $ds['id']; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $ds['nama'];?>" data-alamat="<?php echo $ds['alamat'];?>" data-toggle="modal" class="badge badge success">Edit Profile</a>
```

When your modal popup is shown you can get your datas and can set it to the input fields inside your form. For this you can specify an id selector say **profileForm** for the  field inside your modal popup like,

```
<form id="profileForm" action="<?=base_url('admin/manajemen_akun');?>"    method="post">
```

You can give name attribute to your hidden field.Here I gave name="id"

```
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="<?=$ds['id'];?>">
```

***In your javascript file you can give the following.***

```
$('#editprofile').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get information to update quickly to modal 
 var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal
 //get details from attributes
 var formnama=$(opener).attr('data-name');
 var formalamat=$(opener).attr('data-alamat');
 var id = $(opener).attr('data-id');

 //set it in form
 $('#profileForm').find('[name="formnama"]').val(formnama);
 $('#profileForm').find('[name="formalamat"]').val(formalamat);
 $('#profileForm').find('[name="id"]').val(id); // set id to hidden field whose name="id"

 });
```

Comment: Isn't it better to always use the `data-*`-attribute instead of mixing them with completely custom attributes? So it's `data-user-id=""` instead of `user-id=""`

Comment: yes ,its better to use HTML global data-* attributes. Here I used custom attributes because the person who asked the question may get a flow about how it works.

Comment: When answering a question, you should try to be as accurate as possible. When people see the answer, it's not uncommon for them to see it as how it should be done. Currently, you're showing them a way that you yourself probably wouldn't do (since you know it's better to stick to the `data-*` attribute).